# The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned

Tags: flutter, dart, geocoding

```
  body: FutureBuilder(
  future: determinePosition(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) //error here{
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Text("Error ");
  }else if(snapshot.hasData){
return Column(
children: [
Text(currentAddress),
```

The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'Widget', is a potentially non-nullable type. why it is wrong ? help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're using `else if` instead of `else`. By using *else if*, you're telling Dart to follow this set of conditions, but what if there's `another` condition? that won't be handled, and will return `null`.

To fix the issue, use `else` instead of *else if* in the last clause:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
            future: determinePosition(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return CircularProgressIndicator();
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Text("Error ");
              } else {
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text('test'),
                  ],
                );
              }
            })
```

Answer (score 0):

The potential solution is remove last else if (which is snapshot.hasData) and directly return the the column same as below

```
  body: FutureBuilder(
  future: determinePosition(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) //error here{
  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return CircularProgressIndicator();
  } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
  return Text("Error ");
  }
return Column(
children: [
Text(currentAddress),
```